# nglview installed but will not import inside Juypter Notebook via Anaconda.Navigator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm having trouble importing nglview inside a Juypter Notebook (JNb) cell. The instance of JNb is started via the base (root) Environment inside Anaconda.Navigator GUI. Inside Anaconda.Navigator, I've installed nglview. But the import continues to fail.

Versions:

- Jupyter Notebook (inside Anaconda.Navigator) - 6.4.12
- Anaconda.Navigator (GUI) - 2.3.2
- Python - 3.9
- nglview - 3.0.3 (installed but not importing)
- ipython 8.5.0

This is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 5
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 5 import nglview as nv
      7 # the next line is necessary to display plots in Jupyter
      8 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nglview\__init__.py:4
      1 import warnings
      3 # for doc
----> 4 from . import adaptor, datafiles, show, widget
      5 from ._version import get_versions
      6 from .adaptor import *

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nglview\show.py:13
      3 from . import datafiles
      4 from .adaptor import (ASEStructure, ASETrajectory, BiopythonStructure,
      5                       FileStructure, HTMDTrajectory, IODataStructure,
      6                       IOTBXStructure, MDAnalysisTrajectory, MDTrajTrajectory,
   (...)
     11                       RdkitStructure,
     12                       TextStructure)
---> 13 from .widget import NGLWidget
     15 __all__ = [
     16     'demo',
     17     'show_pdbid',
   (...)
     40     'show_biopython',
     41 ]
     44 def show_pdbid(pdbid, **kwargs):

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nglview\widget.py:19
     15 from traitlets import (Bool, CaselessStrEnum, Dict, Instance, Int, Integer,
     16                        List, Unicode, observe, validate)
     17 import traitlets
---> 19 from . import color, interpolate
     20 from .adaptor import Structure, Trajectory
     21 from .component import ComponentViewer

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nglview\color.py:114
    110         else:
    111             raise ValueError(f"{obj} must be either list of list or string")
--> 114 ColormakerRegistry = _ColormakerRegistry()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nglview\base.py:10, in _singleton.<locals>.getinstance()
      8 def getinstance():
      9     if cls not in instances:
---> 10         instances[cls] = cls()
     11     return instances[cls]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nglview\color.py:47, in _ColormakerRegistry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     45 try:
     46     get_ipython() # only display in notebook
---> 47     self._ipython_display_()
     48 except NameError:
     49     pass

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nglview\color.py:54, in _ColormakerRegistry._ipython_display_(self, **kwargs)
     52 if self._ready:
     53     return
---> 54 super()._ipython_display_(**kwargs)

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_ipython_display_'
```

What is missing? I need to resolve this issue within the GUI of Anaconda.Navigator, as I need nglview as part of an exercise for students who do not have a background in computational sciences. I'm not after a solution that uses anything but the GUI. Asking a group over Zoom to start hacking around with a Mac/Windows/Linux terminal would be a nightmare. Many thanks.

**UPDATE**
Recent efforts have included:

- closing and restarting Anaconda.Navigator GUI
- "Quit" the Jupyter server (option found in the browser tab). Restarted the server.
- `%conda install -c conda-forge nglview` at the top of the Notebook. It just informs me that it's already installed.
- Closing the tab and all mentions of Anaconda and Jupyter (but not the browser window instance itself).

The fact that I haven't restarted the machine itself is a big grey elephant. Unfortunately, it's running a long Quantum chemistry calculation in the background that can't be continued after boot :-( Sorry. But I don't want to get hung up on restarting a machine - it shouldn't come down to that.

Comment: Can I suggest relaunching the Anaconda.Navigator GUI?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it. I relaunched it and did all the basic "turn it off and on again" routines.

Comment: I haven't restarted the machine though... being a stick in the mud and suggested that I shouldn't have to reboot a colossal workstation for this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Anaconda.Navigator GUI but I have often seen latest library installed isn't available inside  a conda environment in the running terminal session - library becomes available after relaunching the terminal, so wanted to suggest that.

Comment: Did you try `%conda install -c conda-forge nglview` in a cell in the notebook where you are trying to work and then restarting the kernel?

Comment: It's already installed, but I tried it, and it told me that it could find the latest version. Thank you for that info, though; I didn't know you could do that. I'm very unfamiliar with Jupyter, I normally spend most of my time inside IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the version of `ipywidget` in your current conda version is above 8.0.0. Because Jupyter notebook is not compatible with the new version of `ipywidget`. Thus try the command below to install the older version of `ipywidget`, then ǹglview` should be properly imported:

`conda install "ipywidgets <8" -c conda-forge`